# Ruby Nokogiri extract text after the end of a tag

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a rather basic question here which means i'm probably missing something i'm using Nokogiri to scrape a site.

I want to extract the text AFTER the end of a strong tag within a div which looks like this:

```
<p style="padding-bottom:0px;"><strong>Location:</strong> Cape Town</p>
```

Currently my code is as follows:

```
location = detail_page.css('p[style="padding-bottom:0px;"]').text
```

Which obviously gives the `<strong>Location:</strong>` bit as well, is there a way to do this **without** using a regex?

The reason for asking is that there are other divs in the same format containing information which I need so I can't just delete the strong elements.

Thanks in advance

Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use XPath:

```
detail_page.xpath('//p[@style="padding-bottom:0px;"]/strong/following-sibling::text()')
```

This selects any text nodes that are following siblings of `strong` elements that are in turn children of `p` elements with a `style` attribute witht he value `padding-bottom:0px;`.

Comment: Thanks, can I specify whats within the strong element?

Comment: @MrkFldig Yes, something like `strong[.="Location:"]`, but if there are multiple `<strong>` element – text pairs in the `p` element you will need to specify just the first text node after the `<strong>` with `following-sibling::text()[1]` (note the `[1]` at the end).

Comment: You my friend are a genius! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here I would do as below :

```
require 'nokogiri'

@doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse('<p style="padding-bottom:0px;"><strong>Location:</strong> Cape Town</p>')
@doc.at_css('p[style*="padding-bottom:0px;"] > text()').text.strip
# => Cape Town
```